# Better logging of Hibernate JPA bean validation

Tags: hibernate, validation, jpa, log4j

I must be missing something but its very hard to figure out what actually failed JPA validation for hibernate.

When validation fail for JPA annotations in hibernate you get an exception like:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: validation failed for classes [com.evocatus.domain.Sauce] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
```

Which is extremely unhelpful.

You can turn on logging for the for what the actually validation failure is through
log4j:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener">
    <level value="TRACE" />
</logger>
```

**YES that is TRACE**.

I must be missing something. Is there a better way to get better error messages on validation failures logged? This is for a REST service.

Comment: I might have to do something with Springs transaction management.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the set of actual *ConstraintViolations*. *ConstraintViolationException* has a *getConstraintViolations()* method which will return a *Set>*.
Arguably the logged exception message could be better ;-)

Comment: Looks like I will have to look at Springs Transaction interceptors as they catch the exception. I want the log level something other than trace (we have a smtp appender for ERROR level).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are not using any framework which deals directly with BeanValidation (like JSF 2), and that's the reason you are not seeing any detail. If you are using plain Hibernate with BeanValidation, you'll need to perform the validation by yourself (usually just before trying to persist). Then, you'd have access to a `Validator` object, from which you can retrieve the actual message. See this example from Hibernate Validator documentation:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

Car car = new Car(null);

Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(car);

assertEquals(1, constraintViolations.size());
assertEquals("may not be null", constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I have to put boiler plate code to do the validation everywhere. I don't have access to the validation objects after the attempted commit because Spring Transaction support kicks in and rolls the transaction back. I probably need either a transaction interceptor or better BeanEventValidationListener.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will print the validation errors in your code from which you can find whee the problem lies

```
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Notice>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(notice);
    for (ConstraintViolation cv : constraintViolations) {
        System.out.println("ValidatationConstraint: " + cv.getConstraintDescriptor().getAnnotation());
        System.out.println("ValidatationConstraint: " + cv.getConstraintDescriptor());
        System.out.println("ValidatationConstraint: " + cv.getMessageTemplate());
        System.out.println("ValidatationConstraint: " + cv.getInvalidValue());
        System.out.println("ValidatationConstraint: " + cv.getLeafBean());
        System.out.println("ValidatationConstraint: " + cv.getRootBeanClass());
        System.out.println("ValidatationConstraint: " + cv.getPropertyPath().toString());
        System.out.println("ValidatationConstraint: " + cv.getMessage());
    }
```